# How to combine 2 SQL-queries with differing number of SELECT-fields

Tags: php, mysql

by using an html-form, I want to read out data from an sql-database and show them in an html-table. The number of the selected criteria is variable and there are two types of selections:

1. criteria can be selected that SHOULD be present (= $request1),

and simultaneously

2. criteria can be selected that SHOULD NOT be present (= $request2).

Both requests are linked by UNION.

My code is:

```
    if (!empty($daten)) {
        $request1 = "SELECT DISTINCT $selection FROM $tabelle WHERE    
            $masterarray";
       } else {
         $request1 = "";
       }


        if ((!empty($daten)) && !empty($contraconcat)) {
        $union1 = "UNION";
       } else {
        $union1 = "";
       }


      if (!empty($contraconcat)) { 
       $request2 = "SELECT DISTINCT p.Name, absent.Comment
       FROM absent_criteria absent
       JOIN product p
       ON p.master_id = absent.product_id
       GROUP BY product_id
       HAVING SUM(absent_criteria IN ($absentselection))=0";
        } else {
          $request2 = "";
        }


        $sql = "$request1
        $union1
        $request2";


        $selection contains the entered selectioncriteria,
        $tabelle the respective tables and
        $masterarray the respective WHERE-conditions
```

Every selection that can be made has a comment-field in the database.
Now, I want to present the results in the html-table with the first column containing the product names. This works well!

In addition, I would like to have the comments of the respective selections in additional columns, each comment of a selection in a separate column. And this is the problem. 
In request2, there is a non-varying number of two fields. However, in request1 the content of $selection is highly variable since the selection here is a dynamic process . But for combining the two SELECT-requests with UNION, I need to have the same number of selections. Is there any possibility to show the comment-columns separately for each selection?

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (!empty($contraconcat)) { 
   $request2 = "SELECT DISTINCT p.Name as Name, absent.Comment as Comment
   FROM absent_criteria absent
   JOIN product p
   ON p.master_id = absent.product_id
   GROUP BY product_id
   HAVING SUM(absent_criteria IN ($absentselection))=0";
    } else {
      $request2 = "";
    }

if (!empty($daten)) {
    if($request2!=""){
       $request1 = "SELECT DISTINCT $selection, table2.Name,table2.Comment
       FROM $tabelle,($request2) as table2         
       WHERE $masterarray";
       //Here maybe you will need to add validation for both tables because it maybe will have many results 
    }
     $request1 = "SELECT DISTINCT $selection FROM $tabelle WHERE    
        $masterarray";
} else {
     $request1 = "";
   }
```

You don't need UNION, because there aren't a same number columns.You need create objects to tables.
First p.Name and absent.Comment have an alias, later validate $request2, if is not null, then build $request2 columns in request1 but see $request2  has an alias table. If $request2 is null then query will not build

Second, you need add an object table to $selection,$tabelle and $masterarray. If query don't build $request1 and $request2, no problem, it works, as this example:

$selection= t.name,t.product

$tabelle= table1 t

$masterarray= t.product LIKE "%R"...

Comment: Thank you Aimeé RP for your suggestion! The Problem is now, that any request selects all products and all columns irrespective of the entered selection criteria. How can I reduce the rows and columns to the selected amount?

Comment: In the code, I wrote a comment to you, you need a validation for both tables, I don't know what there in request1, can you tell me what table or columns are there in request1?, It must to find an union from 2 tables, but if you don't have an union, you can do a validation for ID between both tables, if you don't have an ID for request2, you must to create it, for example: 

request2ID | Name | Comment
     1             name1  comment1

request1ID | ......
     1

Add Validation to your query built
AND request1ID=request2ID

maybe something like that, it will not repeat columns

Comment: In request1 there are the tables color, weight and measures. Could you please give me an example for validation with union and ID?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you don't need UNION, UNION is for 2 select with same number of columns, in your case, check this, for example:

Your request1, for example, your query is:

```
SELECT c.Color as Color,W.Weight as weight,m.Measure as Measure
FROM color c,weight w,measure m
```

Here you must add a temporally ID to the result with ROW_NUMBER()(I don't know what database use, but with row_number works), and $request1 will be:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c.Color DESC) as IDReq1,c.Color as Color,W.Weight as weight,m.Measure as Measure
FROM color c,weight w,measure m
```

For Example,The result for $request1 will be:

IDReq1 | Color | Weight | Measure

1       | White|    10      |   10ft
      2       | Black|    15      |   13ft.....

Later, with request 2, use the same method with ROW_NUMBER, and the result of $request2 will be, for example:

IDReq2 | Name | Comment 
      1      | name1|comment1
      2      | name2|comment2...

Then, when 2 queries are built, JOIN ID respective queries, check this:

```
SELECT table1.Color,table1.Weight,table1.Measure,table2.Name,table2.Comment
FROM ($request1) as table1, ($request2) as table2
WHERE table1.IDReq1=table2.IDReq2
```

The final result will be:

Color | Weight | Measure | Name | Comment

White|    10      |   10ft      | name1|comment1
Black|    15      |   13ft     | name2|comment2

It maybe will help you, but it will depend from your validations
Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for both of your answers Aimeé RP! When I tried your second suggestion, the ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c.Color DESC) worked with $request1 but unfortunately not with $request2. So, I was not able to combine the 2 requests by ID. Is there any problem with the Join-Statement?

Comment: How you did query for $request2 with row_number()? Maybe it's wrong, JOIN statement and my example objects table are the same thing, both need an Id.

Comment: if (!empty($contraconcat)) {
   $request2 = "SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c.Color DESC) as IDReq2, p.Name as Name, absent.Comment as Comment
   FROM absent_criteria absent
   JOIN product p
   ON p.master_id = absent.product_id
   GROUP BY product_id
   HAVING SUM(absent_criteria IN ($absentselection))=0";
    } else {
      $request2 = "";
    }